# Typhoon - How do I inject a UIView defined in a xib file?

Tags: typhoon

I want to inject a view into my view controller so that I can inject a mock view in my unit tests (`WPDependencyInjectorImplementation` is my `TyphoonAssembly` subclass).

My ideal `loadView` method would look like the following:

```
- (void)loadView {
    WPDependencyInjectorImplementation *injectorAssembly = (WPDependencyInjectorImplementation *) [TyphoonAssembly defaultAssembly];
    self.view = [injectorAssembly someView];
}
```

I'm not sure what the definition for this would look like or whether it's possible, given that the code for creating a view from a xib is the following:

```
NSArray *views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"WPSomeView" owner:nil options:nil];
return [views firstObject];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right you just override loadView, rather than looking up the view from the container, as you've shown, you should provide the view via an initializer or property setter. And then in loadView, set it to the injected view as follows:

```
- (void)loadView 
{
    [self.view = _myInjectedView]; //Do this rather than looking it up via the TyphoonFactory - easier to test. 
}
```

If you do it this way:

- You can refer to the view via it's actual type, rather than down-casting from UIView
- It'll be really simple to mock-out in a pure unit test. (No need for [TyphoonPatcher](http://www.typhoonframework.org/docs/latest/api/interface_typhoon_patcher.html), swizzling, etc).

Here's an example:

```
- (id)userDetailsController
{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[UserDetailsController class] initialization:^(TyphoonInitializer* initializer)
    {
        initializer.selector = @selector(initWithSession:userDetailsView:);
        [initializer injectWithDefinition:[self session]];
        [initializer injectWithDefinition:[self userDetailsView]];
    }];
}

- (id)userDetailsView
{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[UserDetailsView class] 
        properties:^(TyphoonDefinition* definition)
    {
        //circular dependency. Can also be set within VC. 
        [definition injectProperty:@selector(delegate) 
            withDefinition:[self userDetailsController]]; 
        [definition injectProperty:@selector(sideMargin) 
            withValueAsText:@"${view.field.default.side.margin}"];
    }];
}
```

**Injecting From a Xib**

We don't actually have a Xib factory we can provide you yet. It should be a quick job to define one using a similar pattern to the object that emits a theme [here](https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon-example/blob/master/PocketForecast/Assembly/Blocks/PFThemeProvider.m), so you'll have a component in the DI container for each of your Xib-based views, and just inject that directly.

Alternatively you could use our new [TyphoonFactoryProvider](http://www.typhoonframework.org/docs/latest/api/interface_typhoon_factory_provider.html).

If you get stuck, please let us know and one of us will find some time to create and push that Xib-view-factory for you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I've gone with the injected view approach and I think it's definitely better for testing.

I'll take a look into your suggestions for loading xib-views.

Comment: you're welcome. If you need help with the xib-view factory please log an issue in GitHub and we'll have one created. Otherwise, if you get it done yourself we'd love a pull-request for that actually.